# Looking for an open source project based on Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, open-source

Hei

I’m trying to learn Linq to SQL and wondering if somebody can suggest some demo/open source project based on Linq to SQL.
Preferably full designed n–layer architecture, showing best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) tutorial or the [NerdDinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) tutorial.  Both are complete walkthroughs with code and PDFs to explain each step.  Note though that each of these are MVC project walkthroughs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you visit [codeproject.com](http://codeproject.com) in such cases, as it has tons of info on this and other topics, explaining technologies, frameworks, approaches and all that in sample projects that you can download any time.